# How do you differentiate between Windows 8 RTM and Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation?

Tags: windows-8

This has created a lot of confusion. The Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation cannot be upgraded and it will expire in 90 days. On the other hand the one from MSDN - Windows 8 RTM has no such restrictions.

Is it so that both Windows 8 RTM and Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation ARE the same?

Also, is it possible to obtain ONLY the key for Windows 8 RTM from DreamSpark Premium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To be exact, these are the additional features available with Window 8 Enterprise:**

- **Device encryption**  – Device encryption, a feature introduced in Windows Mobile 6.5, encrypts the contents of a mobile device to enhance their security. Most of the organizations/enterprises would require this feature inorder to safeguard their business data.
- **Windows To Go** – is a feature in Windows 8 Enterprise that allows Windows 8 Enterprise to boot and run from USB mass storage devices such as flash drives and external hard drives. It is a fully manageable corporate Windows 8 environment. It is intended to allow enterprise administrators to provide users with an imaged version of Windows 8 that reflects the corporate desktop and as such is aimed at enterprises. Creation of Windows To Go drives is not supported by other Windows 8 editions.
- **DirectAccess** -  is a VPN-like technology that provides intranet connectivity to client computers when they are connected to the Internet. Unlike many traditional VPN connections, which must be initiated and terminated by explicit user action, DirectAccess connections are designed to connect automatically as soon as the computer connects to the Internet. DirectAccess was introduced in Windows Server 2008 R2, providing this service to Windows 7 clients (Ultimate and Enterprise editions only).
- **BranchCache** - a feature of Windows 7 and later, locally caches contents received from a file server or web server to enable faster subsequent uses.
- **Virtualized by RemoteFX** – Windows 8 Enterprise can be virtualized using RemoteFX – a set of Remote Desktop virtualization technology by Microsoft to enhance visual experience of the Remote Desktop Protocol.
- **Modern UI Style App deployment** *(of internal applications)* – you can deploy MetroUI/Windows Store internal applications hosted internally in your organization network.

**You Can Claim Just the key from DreamSpark:**

- If your a student and have a legit account, you should be able to claim the key.
- It work's similar to the BizSpark account, which is for budding Entrepreneurs.
- Attaching a screenshot on how to claim a key.
  [image: Claim a Key]

Comment: So, if I acquire the Windows 8 RTM from MSDN/ DS Premium, I won't have the above mentioned features. And I can't deploy Win8 apps in the RTM?

Comment: @AbhishekSha You cannot deploy Apps internally to your organization network. You CAN definitely deloy your own developed apps to the Windows Store.

Comment: @aliasgar Some of those features are not available in the evaluation version. I have also noticed you cannot change the network type for any network connection, by default they are all "public" in enterprise evaluation version

Comment: @Moab, i would appreciate it if you could help me correct my answer if anything is wrong. I just defined it elaborately. Check the table at this source, and the evaluation version is normally a full version deployed by Microsoft with an expiry date: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Comment: @aliasgar I think evaluation version is slightly different than Enterprise RTM, I have eval version installed on a PC, so its based on what I am seeing on my install. The differences are not documented anywhere I can find.

Comment: @Moab no issues, i dont want to disagree with you. I just have a valid full version installed coz of bizspark, but when i dint enter a key, it went into evaluation, and i got all the features. Might be the build difference!